# How to decrypt AWS S3 file during download?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

Here is my download code :

```
 IAmazonS3 client;

            string key = tenant_id + @"/files/" + filename;
            try
            {
                using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
                {
                    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = existingBucketName,
                        Key = key
                    };

                    using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                    {
                        string dest = path;
                        if (!File.Exists(dest))
                        {
                            response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
```

I would like to decrypt files during the download process. I've gone through the support docs but unable to proceed. What changes do I need to make in my current code to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the file was encrypted. S3 supports [client-side encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) and [server-side encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html).

If the file is encrypted using server-side encryption, either S3 is managing the keys or you need to provide the key in your request. If the file was encrypted client-side prior to being uploaded to S3 then you must decrypt the downloaded file yourself. In this case check out the [AmazonS3EncryptionClient](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxL15A0QZMD38D/Client-Side-Data-Encryption-with-AWS-SDK-for-NET-and-Amazon-S3) to help make things easier.